# How to optimise a large image with Astro?

Tags: javascript, pagespeed, astrojs, image-optimization

I am trying to optimise a 2.4 MB image (4514x5789) with Astro.

I tried:

```
<Image
  src={Image}
  alt="image"
  quality={80}
  format="webp"
  loading="lazy"
  widths={[390, Image.width]}
  sizes={`(max-width: 768) 390px, ${Image.width}px`}
  class="rounded-lg"
/>
```

Unfortunately this is not enough according to [PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-daniell-dev/9jckue9erj?form_factor=mobile). What can I change to get a performance score of 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Astro docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/images/#widths), the `widths` attribute you're providing will be used to generate the `srcset` in HTML.

Here's what that looks like on your page:

```html
<img
  src="/_vercel/image?url=_astro%2Fdaniell.ewbYQu3K.jpg&amp;w=3840&amp;q=80" 
  alt="Daniell sitting"
  loading="lazy"
  widths="390,4514"
  sizes="(max-width: 768) 390px, 4514px"
  class="rounded-lg"
  width="4514"
  height="5789"
  decoding="async">
```

It seems the problem is that you're passing the width of the original image as one of the potential sizes for the `srcset`. On devices smaller than 768px, the 390px version of the image will be used. On devices wider than 768px, the full 4514px image will be used instead.

It also seems that the largest the image could actually render on the page is 390px, so you don't need any sources larger than that. To fix the issue, try removing `Image.width` from `widths` and `sizes`:

```
<Image
  src={Image}
  alt="image"
  quality={80}
  format="webp"
  loading="lazy"
  widths={[390]}
  sizes="390px"
  class="rounded-lg"
/>
```

Comment: Seems like it got slightly better on desktop but no change on mobile. Is there anything else worth trying? [latest run](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-daniell-dev/qo3hgnhd4d?hl=nl&form_factor=mobile)

Comment: It doesn't seem like the 390px version of the image is being generated correctly: https://daniell.dev/_vercel/image?url=_astro%2Fdaniell.ewbYQu3K.jpg&w=3840&q=80. Changing the `w` param to 390 results in a 400 error. Is that URL generated by Astro or Vercel?

Comment: I'm not too sure but at least I know where to look

Comment: Hard coding the width and height seems to have done it!